# I could not see the pages which I had created using CMS after Updating the security Patch

Tags: magento-1.8, supee-6788

I had installed latest security patch of SUPEE-6788 after installing this security patch.I could not see the before created CMS pages in frontend.It is showing the URL but it is not showing the data on the page.

EX:I had created the CMS page in admin with content:

```
 <p>{{block type='core/template' name='tools'    template='tools/donorform.phtml'}}</p>
```

In the same folder I placed the donorform.phtml.Before It has shown the form.But after Installing the security patch the form is not showing.

Please anyone can help me.

donorfom.phtml

```
  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar-setup.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js') ?>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css"  />
  <?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_calendar')->setTemplate('page/js/calendar.phtml')->toHtml();?>

    <form action="http://www.labwise.in/devel/blood-donor/submit" id="blooddonor" method="post">
<div class="fieldset">
<h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Requisition Details:') ?></h2>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="bloodgroup" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Required Blood Group') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                            <select name="bloodgroup" id="bloodgroup" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                                    <option value="A+"><?php echo $this->__('A+')?></option>
                                    <option value="A-"><?php echo $this->__('A-')?></option>

                                    <option value="AB+"><?php echo $this->__('AB+')?></option>
                                    <option value="AB-"><?php echo $this->__('AB-')?></option>
                                    <option value="B+"><?php echo $this->__('B+')?></option>
                                    <option value="B-"><?php echo $this->__('B-')?></option>
                                    <option value="O+"><?php echo $this->__('O+')?></option>
                                    <option value="O-"><?php echo $this->__('O-')?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="field"> 

            <label for="unitsrequired " class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Units Required ') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                            <select name="unitsrequired" id="unitsrequired" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                                    <option value="1"><?php echo $this->__('1')?></option>
                                    <option value="2"><?php echo $this->__('2')?></option>
                                    <option value="3"><?php echo $this->__('3')?></option>
                                    <option value="4"><?php echo $this->__('4')?></option>
                                    <option value="5"><?php echo $this->__('5')?></option>
                                    <option value="6"><?php echo $this->__('6')?></option>
                                    <option value="7"><?php echo $this->__('7')?></option>
                                    <option value="8"><?php echo $this->__('8')?></option>
                                    <option value="9"><?php echo $this->__('9')?></option>
                                    <option value="10"><?php echo $this->__('10')?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="requiredby" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Required By (Date )') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="requiredby" name="requiredby" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Required By (Date )') ?>" style="width: 150px;" />
                        <img style="" title="Select Date" id="date_select_trig" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/calendar.gif");?> "/>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field"> 

                <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" />
                    </div>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="hospital" ><?php echo $this->__('Hospital (Optional)') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="hospital" name="hospital" value="" class="input-text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Hospital (Optional)') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="fieldset">
<h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Seeker Details:') ?></h2>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">

        <div class="field">
            <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field">
         <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="scity" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="scity" name="scity" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" />
                    </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="yourbloodgroup" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Your Blood Group') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                            <select name="yourbloodgroup" id="yourbloodgroup"class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                                    <option value="A+"><?php echo $this->__('A+')?></option>
                                    <option value="A-"><?php echo $this->__('A-')?></option>

                                    <option value="AB+"><?php echo $this->__('AB+')?></option>
                                    <option value="AB-"><?php echo $this->__('AB-')?></option>
                                    <option value="B+"><?php echo $this->__('B+')?></option>
                                    <option value="B-"><?php echo $this->__('B-')?></option>
                                    <option value="O+"><?php echo $this->__('O+')?></option>
                                    <option value="O-"><?php echo $this->__('O-')?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
          </li>
          <li>

          <label for="checkbox"  class="required"><em>*</em> </label>
          <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="required" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> Accept terms and conditions
         </div>
         </li>

         <div class="button">
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
    </ul>
 </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[

if(Validation) {
    Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
    function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

    var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
    // var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
    if(v.length > 0){
    if(v.length !=10){
        return false;
       }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

        return false;
       }


    return true;

    }else {
    return false;
    }

    }
    ]])};

var contactForm = new VarienForm('blooddonor', true);
//]]>
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
   Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'requiredby',
    ifFormat : '%d-%b-%Y',
    showsTime: false,
    button : 'date_select_trig',
    singleClick : true,
     });
     // ]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks and custom variables now need to be added to a whitelist.  You'll need to login to the admin panel and go to `System > Permissions > Variables` and add any custom variables used by your block to the list.

Comment: It is showing empty page after going to this path in admin panel System > Permissions > Variables.

Comment: @STWplease help me I need it very soon it has screwed up.

Comment: @Mouni I'd be glad to help, could you post the contents of your `tools/donorform.phtml` template?

Comment: Attached the tools/donorform.phtml code the code is placed in app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/tools/donorfrom.phtml